# Bring system in normal form up to the second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, transformation

> > Bring the system 
> >     $$\begin{cases}
> > x'=y+xz,\\ y'=x^2+y^2+z^2,\\z'=-2z+xy
> > \end{cases}$$
> >     to a normal form up to the second order (kill all non-resonant quadratic terms).

The equilibrium is $(0,0,0)$ and the linearization matrix is
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix},
$$
hence the eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0,\lambda_3=-2.
$$

- In the first equation, the term $xz$ is non-resonant.
- In the second equation, the term $z^2$ is non-resonant.
- In the third equation, the term $xy$ is non-resonant.

**Edit due to Jonas' help in the comments**

Let 
$$\begin{cases}
X=x+a_1y^2+a_2yz+a_3z^2,\\ Y=y+b_1x^2+b_2xz+b_3 z^2,\\ Z=z+c_1x^2+c_2xy+c_3 y^2\end{cases}
$$

Put this into the ODEs, i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
X'=Y+XZ=y+b_1x^2+b_2xz+b_3z^2+xz+\text{ terms of 3rd order or higher}&(1)\\
Y'=X^2+Y^2+Z^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+\text{ terms of 3rd order or higher}&(2)\\
Z'=-2z-2c_1x^2-2c_2xy-2c_3y^2+xy+\text{ terms of 3rd order or higher}&(3).
\end{cases}$$

From (1), we get that
$$
b_1=b_3=0, b_2=-1.
$$

But I do not know how to get the other coeffcients $a_i, c_i, i=1,2,3$ from (2) and (3).

Comment: You also need to take (new) $Y$ and $Z$. Substitute in the equation and choose the coefficients $a$, etc, so that hte nonresonant terms disappear. But it depends on what you want. In most cases it is irrelevant to know the specific change of variables.

Comment: Example: $X'=x'+2ayy'+\cdots=y+xz+2ay(x^2+y^2+z^2)+\cdots$ and you need to choose the constants so that $XZ=\cdots$ is not there. Better in fact to always write $x$ in terms of $X$, $Y$, $Z$, etc.

Comment: You have to consider all, since otherwise you could obtain new terms of order $2$. But as I said, it is better to write $x=X+$polynomial in $X,Y,Z$, etc, and replace in the equation, leading to something like $X'=Y+$higher order terms. Then you choose the coefficients so that *all* terms of order $2$ vanish.

Comment: You have to write it in terms of $X,Y,Z$, not $x,y,z$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot afford the time of writing it myself. It is only a change of variables, so you need to plug in $X,Y,Z$ (as I wrote above) in the original equations and after some computations will will be able to choose the constants in the change of variables so that all the order $2$ terms disappear.

Comment: A good reference would be the book by Guckenheimer and Holmes.

Comment: I despair of this! It simply does not work! . .

Comment: See my answer below. To write more is impossible, since this would take too much time.

Answer (score 2):

What is below is done by brute force. It is not what the theory recommends (neither it is useful in general), but it is what you ask.

Write
$$x=X+a_1X^2+b_1Y^2+c_1Z^2+d_1XY+e_1XZ+f_1YZ,$$
$$y=Y+a_2X^2+b_2Y^2+c_2Z^2+d_2XY+e_2XZ+f_2YZ,$$
$$z=Z+a_3X^2+b_3Y^2+c_3Z^2+d_3XY+e_3XZ+f_3YZ.$$
Then
$$x'=X'+2a_1XX'+2b_1YY'+2c_1ZZ'+\cdots$$
while
$$
\begin{split}
y+xz
&=Y+a_2X^2+b_2Y^2+c_2Z^2+d_2XY+e_2XZ+f_2YZ+\\
&\quad(X+a_1X^2+b_1Y^2+c_1Z^2+d_1XY+e_1XZ+f_1YZ)\times\\
&\quad(Z+a_3X^2+b_3Y^2+c_3Z^2+d_3XY+e_3XZ+f_3YZ).
\end{split}
$$
You do the same for the other two equations. Since $x'=y+xz$, etc, you obtain $3$ equations that you can use to find $X',Y',Z'$. You need to express the right-hand sides as Taylor series, after which you will get for example$$X'=Y+(\text{expression in terms of the constants})YZ+\cdots.$$
It is the expression in the line above (and all others that you know that may be erased) that give equations to find the (possible) constants.

In practice this is not very effective and it is much better to solve the homological equations. For that, again I recommend the book by Guckenheimer and Holmes.

Comment: I am wondering why in the coordinate trafo for example of $x$, there appear terms that contain $X^2$ and $XY$ and so on. I always thought one only makes polynomal transforms only containing combinations of the other two variables y and z. Hm, okay. I think this is a bit too difficult to me.

Comment: Am I right with the following: In general, in polynomial coordinate trafos we consider  possible combinations of ALL three variables (here: x,y,z) of some special order. But in case (for example in terms of center manifold, when we have for example $x=\varphi(y,z)$ we would only consider combinations of y and x polynomial terms for coordinate trafo of $x$?

Comment: I did the calculation and my result is that $a_3=b_2=b_3=d_2=e_2=e_3=f_2=f_3=0$ and $c_1=-1$ and $c_2=c_3=f_1=\frac{1}{4}$ and $d_3=e_1=\frac{1}{2}$. For the other coefficients I have that $d_1=a_2$ and that $a_1$ and $b_1$ are not determined, i.e. $a_1$ and $b_1$ can be any values.  - Do you think this might be correct?

Comment: So the possible transformations are $X=x+a_1x^2+b_1y^2-z^2+a_2xy+\frac{1}{2}xz+\frac{1}{4}yz,~~Y=y+a_2y^2+\frac{1}{4}z^2,~~Z=z+\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{1}{2}xy$, where $a_1,a_2,b_1\in\mathbb{R}$. - Hope this is correct.

Comment: Without resorting to the theory (which says that the transformations can always be done at the level of homogeneous polynomials) this is indeed the best you can do (that's also what I mean by brute force). Using the restrictions to homogeneous polynomials, you would know exactly what is expected as a change of variable to eliminate each nonresonant term (and you wouldn't need to consider all the constants above). Also, in general the required change of variables might not be unique, as you are obtaining.

Comment: True what you say above about center manifolds, but this is not related to finding normal forms. In other words, normals forms are quite useful along center manifolds, but that's not the only reason why they are useful.